# Duplicate each element of a vector and add "a" to odd and "b" to even elements

Tags: r, vector

This is my original vector (the length can vary)

```
c("e1","e2","e3","e4","e5","e6","e7","e8","e9","e10")
```

I would like to duplicate each element (keeping the order) and attribute "a" to the first occurrence and "b" to the second, to get:

```
c("e1a","e1b","e2a","e2b","e3a","e3b","e4a","e4b","e5a","e5b","e6a","e6b","e7","e7b","e8a","e8b","e9a","e9b","e10a","e10b")
```

How can I do this in a nice and compact way in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rep(each = 2)` to get the duplication and then use `paste0` to add the suffix letters as below.

This is a nice example of vector recycling; `paste0` will use the elements of `c("a", "b")` until the length of the longer vector is exhausted automatically. As a consequence, you can do this with any length of the original `vec`. Many base and package R functions will do something similar.

```r
vec <- c("e1","e2","e3","e4","e5","e6","e7","e8","e9","e10")
paste0(rep(vec, each = 2), c("a", "b"))
#>  [1] "e1a"  "e1b"  "e2a"  "e2b"  "e3a"  "e3b"  "e4a"  "e4b"  "e5a"  "e5b" 
#> [11] "e6a"  "e6b"  "e7a"  "e7b"  "e8a"  "e8b"  "e9a"  "e9b"  "e10a" "e10b"
```

Created on 2018-08-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).